# Source List required

Tags: apt, updates, source

Require exact source list for:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Comment: Once you've enabled source code for your machine; you can `apt source` to download source code for whatever parts (*packages*) of your system you want.  If you want to restore you source files, whilst you mention a release, you didn't specify more than that (product, eg. Server, Desktop, let alone architecture) as the sources.list varies on those details (*particularly architecture!*)